# Double thesis or double topic in thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis

This is a pretty hypothetical scenario, but it could apply to me based on how the next two years of my PhD go.

Let's say a PhD student in math/applied math has two ongoing projects, both of which are potentially thesis quality, yet only tangentially related to each other. As is generally true in research, it's not clear how impactful or successful each of these projects will go, and the student wants to keep working on both.

Is it possible for a thesis to be split over two unrelated topics? And what happens if both of these topics end up successful (i.e. end up being developed into a full thesis)? Would we pick only one of them to end up as the 'official' thesis?

Comment: This is a question for your advisor and your department.

Comment: Some related questions: [PhD Thesis based on published articles on different topics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/89874/17254), [Has a "portfolio" of orthogonal projects ever been acceptable for a PhD thesis, instead of a single large project?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104501/17254), [Can a (stapler) PhD thesis comprise multiple unrelated papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/135248/17254)

Comment: @Anyon Ah thanks!!